# Camel Kafka .NET Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I'm new to Camel and Kafka.  I have been reading some documentation on Camel, and have come across [this repository](https://github.com/apache/camel-kafka-connector-examples) with links to number of connectors.  These seem to be connectors to primary sources of storage.  What if I need to connect from .NET, pull the data and process it before committing it to my database?  I feel like I'm missing the point somehow as I don't see any kinds of C# connectors.

Comment: Camel is a Java framework. You only need a Kafka client. However, Kafka Connect is the recommended way to interact with a database rather than handling batching, exceptions, and offset commits on your own

Answer (score 2):

Camel kafka connector project aims to provide a set of kafka connectors ready to use by simply configuring them. These connectors are based on the corresponding Camel components, that in turn focus on talking with an "external" system, protocol or SaaS.

So if I understood you usecase you probably need a kafka client in C# (like https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) so in your application logic you can connect to kafka grab events, apply what logic is needed and place them in the application database.

Comment: That's right. Thanks so much for the link.  Will take a look!  If that is the case, then what would the use case be for using something like Camel?

Comment: Apache Camel itself in 2 words is an integration framework. You can find much better details and explanation [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/what-is-camel.html). [Camel Kafka Connect](https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/latest/index.html) in turn is a sub project of Apache Camel that makes you use camel components inside the [Kafka Connect](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect) ecosystem. Essentially enabling you to ingest data into or or stream data out of a Kafka broker targeting more than 300 types of external systems with just configuration.